# properties name of an Laravel Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this Object in Laravel:

```
array:144 [▼
  0 => {#10 ▼
    +"year": 2005
    +"month": "ene"
    +"FOO": "37"
    +"BAR": "17"
  }
  1 => {#11 etc...
```

I need to put the names "year", "month", "FOO" and "BAR" as  in a table:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach($data as $column_name)
            <th><strong>{{ $column_name }}</strong></th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</thead>
```

$data is the Object.

So the table should looke like:

```
year | month | FOO | BAR
------------------------
2005    ene    37   17
```

The values are working fine, but I don't know how to retrieve the name of the properties to build the

EDIT:

This Is what I get according to some answers:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$data` is the first `stdClass` object in the `array`, then you should be able to do the following:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach((array) $data[0] as $key => $value)
            <th><strong>{{ $key }}</strong></th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: What I get there is the keys (0,1, etc) as <th>'s

Comment: Then `$data` isn't the object as you stated in your question, it's the array of objects.

Comment: Me too (my question with some pics)

Comment: My change will fix your first problem. Your `foreach($data as $data)` isn't going to work for the body, because you're overwriting the value for `$data` in each iteration of the loop. Change the second variable to something different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach($data as $key)
            <th><strong>{{ $key['year'] }}</strong></th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</thead>
```

**Update:**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach($data as $key)
            <th><strong>{{ $key->year }}</strong></th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: You could always cast it to an array first. `(array) $data`